# Choreography of making many yorkshire puddings

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

Say you want to make a lot (>4) yorkshire puddings, but your form only has 4 molds. What is your choreography?

Do you ...

- stack several forms in the oven
- use one form, take out the pouddings when done and refill the hot form immediatly with fat and batter
- something else entirely

Background: I'm about to buy a form as a present for my mother, who often cooks for more people. The question is: Is it worth it to buy two forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would buy two tins, for the reason that one of the most important factors for successful Yorkshires is a good hot oven. This is required to convert the water in the batter into steam quickly, causing the puddings to rise. Your oven loses a *lot* of heat when you open the door, so you will more than likely get a poor rise on your second batch if you reuse the tin.

So, I would use two tins, then you can keep that door closed until the last possible minute.

Comment: Interesting. My thought was to reuse one tin so the tin can retain it's heat.

Comment: You can get the pan as hot as you like, but if the oven's cold it won't do you any good

Comment: How do you get your pudding into the oven in the first place, without losing all the heat? And why should it be different the second time?

Comment: Overheating it to compensate. But then you adjust the temperature down to stop the Yorkshires burning.

Answer (score 1):

Personally at home I use two trays at a time. They easily both fit in the oven together, with enough room for proper airflow.

More important to me is, I start my Yorkys at 230°c for 5min and then turn to oven down to 180°c for 20min. If I was to do one tray at a time I'd have to wait for the oven to get back from 180°c to 230°c before putting my next batch in. In total probably costing me 2 hours for 8 Yorkshires once you've accounted for resting of the batter etc. A little excessive for a simple gravy soak-er if you ask me.

Splash out, get her two and save her an hour of her life :)